# VS2015 New web form pages created empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've been away from .Net web dev for a few years and am now coming back to it in order to update a client project. I've installed VS Pro 2015 and am now experiencing some odd behaviours both with the project/website files and VS.

The first 'issue' I need to tackle is that when adding a new master page or webform to the project, these new documents appear completely empty. There is no code or markup generated in the documents eg: 'docname.master', 'docname.master.cs', 'pagename.aspx', 'pagename.aspx.cs'.

I doubt this is the correct, behaviour since it wasn't in the past. So have things changed, and this is expected, and I need to get up to speed. Or, is there something wrong with my set-up? If so, what am I doing wrong? What can I do to rectify this?

**UPDATE**

I've just done some testing on a different machine and it appears that this seems to be connected to the fact that the files I've been working with are located on a network file server. Is this a known issue, and are there any fixes/workarounds?

Comment: They should not be empty. Take a look in your C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates folder and locate the templates for the items you are selecting and see if they are there, and if they look correct.

Comment: Thanks for the info & suggestion. Ive had a look in that folder but I just see a bunch of numbered folders, each with seemingly randomly named subfolder. Inside those is a bunch of files. I don't really know which I'm looking for or how to examine them for validity. Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: @StingyJack Ive added some new info to my OP.

Comment: The subfolder names in the folder I listed should be things like "CloudService", "CSharp", "Web", "Test", etc. Try reinstalling the item templates by running "devenv /installvstemplates" from an administrative cmd prompt (more info at https://goo.gl/88dSwD ) and see if that fixes your installation. If not, consider re-installing VS.

Comment: Its the folder below that, that are confusing. Anyway, it looks like the issue was due to the project being on a network drive. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it turns out that the cause of this and several other issues was purely down to the fact that the project files I was working with were located on a network drive.

It appears that this is a fairly common problem, especially when access to the network / remote drive is quite slow.

Simply switching the project files to a local drive fixed all the problem I was experiencing.